# Dealing with (members of) heterogeneous arrays

Tags: powershell

Let's create books

```
$a = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
$a | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Title –Value "Journey to the West" 
$a | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Price –Value 12

$b = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
$b | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Title –Value "Faust" 
$b | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Author –Value "Goethe"

$array1 = $a,$b
$array2 = $b,$a
```

Now let's display these two arrays

```
PS D:\Developpement\Powershell> $array1

Title               Price
-----               -----
Journey to the West    12
Faust                    

PS D:\Developpement\Powershell> $array2

Title               Author
-----               ------
Faust               Goethe
Journey to the West
```

So as far as I understand this basically means that what powershell consider to be properties of an array are the properties of its **first** element (in fact that's not even true because if the first element is `$null` the next one will be considered). Now that also implies that :

- if you call `Get-Member` on the array, you will only get members of the first element
- if you call `Convert-ToCvs` on the array, you will only export property values for properties defined by the first element
- etc

I hardly understand the rationals behind that and this behaviour has made it infuriatingly painful for me to work with heterogeneous arrays in powershell.

I'd like to import data from various external sources, process them and then export them to a cvs file. Items are similar but most of them miss some properties unpredictably. Is there any obvious way to handle that in Powershell without reprogramming the wheel?

Comment: `$array|select ($array|%{$_.PSObject.Properties}|select -exp name -u)|ConvertTo-Csv`

Comment: `Get-Member` shows the membersets for the first object of each distinct type in the array. `$a.pstypenames.Insert(0,"BookForSale"); $a1|gm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way it has to be because PowerShell uses pipelines. When you run ex. `$array1 | Export-CSV ....`, PowerShell starts to write to the CSV-file as soon as the first object arrives. At that point it needs to know what the header will look like as that is the first line in a csv-file. So PowerShell has to assume that the class/properties of the first object represents all the remaining objects in the pipeline. The same goes for `Format-Table` and similar commands that need to set a style/view before outputting any objects.

The usual workaround to this is to specify the header manually using `Select-Object`. It will add all missing properties to all objects with a value of `$null`. This way, all the objects sent to ex. `Export-CSV` will have all the same properties defined.

To get the header, you need to receive all unique property-names from all objects in your array. Ex.

```
$array1 |
ForEach-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties} |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -Unique

Title
Price
Author
```

Then you can specify that as the header using `Select-Object -Properties Title,Price,Author` before sending the objects to `Export-CSV` Ex:

```
$a = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
$a | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Title –Value "Journey to the West" 
$a | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Price –Value 12

$b = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
$b | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Title –Value "Faust" 
$b | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Author –Value "Goethe"

$array = $a,$b

$AllProperties = $array |
ForEach-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties} |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -Unique

$array | Select-Object -Property $AllProperties | Export-CSV -Path "mycsv.out" -NoTypeInformation
```

This will create this CSV-file:

```
"Title","Price","Author"
"Journey to the West","12",
"Faust",,"Goethe"
```

If you have mulltiple arrays you can combine them like this `$array = $array1 + $array2`